# Python regex re.sub : something

Tags: python, regex

I have a program like this :

```
import re

x='aaaaaaaa;aa;aaa;aaa;aaaaaaaaaa;'
x=re.sub(';','.',x, re.IGNORECASE)

print x
```

But the output is like this:

```
aaaaaaaa.aa.aaa;aaa;aaaaaaaaaa;
```

There are still some `;` not replaced by a `.`, why ?

Using Python 2.6

Comment: Using "ignorecase" when replacing `;` doesn't seem to make much sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update - In Python 2.6 you can just do this:**

```
>>> re.sub('(?i);','.',x)
'aaaaaaaa.aa.aaa.aaa.aaaaaaaaaa.'
```

**For Python 2.7+ and 3.0+**

Do this instead, the third parameter is actually the count(number of replacements to make) and `re.IGNORECASE` is simply an integer so it is using that as the count.

```
>>> re.sub(';','.',x, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
'aaaaaaaa.aa.aaa.aaa.aaaaaaaaaa.'

>>> re.IGNORECASE
2
```

Comment: It gives me an error with python 2.6: TypeError: sub() got an unexpected keyword argument 'flags' (but it's work with the 2.7 version thank you ^^)

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? EDIT: Nvm read your comment

Comment: You can change your pattern to `'(?i);'` which does the same thing

Comment: (?i) came very handy as I need to be using python2.6 for the work I'm doing.